# run xamarin.ios App from visual studio 2013?

Tags: ios, macos, mobile, xamarin.ios, xamarin

i using xamarin on vs2013, i try to develop xamarin.forms project {android, windows phone and ios}, I need to run ios app.
i have mac PC on my net work and need to run **xamarin.ios** project from visual studio 2013 to iPhone emulator on mac PC that is connected on the same network ?

thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to start the Xamarin Build Host on your Mac. All you need to know can be found [here](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/installation/windows/introduction_to_xamarin_ios_for_visual_studio/).

Comment: You will also need a business level or higher license to build iOS apps in visual studio

Comment: thanks **asp_net** and  **Clint Landry** i  run Xamarin.ios Build Host but as **Clint Landry** say that I need a business level or higher license. Is there any workaround for this ??